# Why is module math called "built-in"?

Tags: python

AFAIK, Python `builtins` refers to those exceptions and functions contained in `__builtins__`:

```
>>> import builtins  # import __builtin__ in Python 2
>>> dir(builtins)  # dir(__builtin__) for Python 2
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException',
'BlockingIOError', 'BrokenPipeError', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning',
...many more...
'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'repr', 'reversed',
'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum',
'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip']
```

But look at the code below (both Python2 and 3 gave the same results):

```
>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>,
 '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> import threading
>>> import math
>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 
 '__doc__': None, '__package__': None,
 'threading': <module 'threading' from C:\\ProgramFiles\\Python3.3\\lib\\threading.py'>,
 'math': <module 'math' (built-in)>}
```

On the last line, module `math` is called `built-in`. Why? What's the difference between module `math` and other modules like `threading`?

Comment: `import builtins` gives `ImportError` (Python 2.7)

Comment: @JayanthKoushik `import __builtin__` in Python2

Comment: For the record, my interpreter (2.7.3) does **not** call `math` a built-in module: `'math': <module 'math' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so'>`.

Comment: The "built-in" marker for the `math` module doesn't say that it's part of `__builtins__` (a module containing built-in functions and types such as `open` and `int`), but that the module was built directly into the interpreter during compilation of Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs (`./Doc/library/stdtypes.rst`):

> ### Modules
>
> ...
>
> Modules built into the interpreter are written like this: `<module 'sys' (built-in)>`.  If loaded from a file, they are written as `<module 'os' from '/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/os.pyc'>`.

The relevant code is in the `repr()` function for the module object:

```
static PyObject *
module_repr(PyModuleObject *m)
{
    char *name;
    char *filename;

    name = PyModule_GetName((PyObject *)m);
    if (name == NULL) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        name = "?";
    }
    filename = PyModule_GetFilename((PyObject *)m);
    if (filename == NULL) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        return PyString_FromFormat("<module '%s' (built-in)>", name);
    }
    return PyString_FromFormat("<module '%s' from '%s'>", name, filename);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case the `math` module was included into the main Python library itself (`libpython2.7.{so,dll,dylib}`) when the library was built. This is possible since the module is written in C rather than pure Python. Other modules that are like this include `sys` and `posix`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/intro.html) have this to say:

> The bulk of the library, however, consists of a collection of modules. There are many ways to dissect this collection. Some modules are written in C and built in to the Python interpreter; others are written in Python and imported in source form.

The `math` module is in C and is built into the interpreter, whereas `threading` is in Python, and imported in source.